# When I use HttpResponseRedirect I get TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes in Django

Tags: python, django

When trying to implement a custom `get_success_url` method in python, Django throws a `TypeError: quote_from_bytes()`error. For example:

```
class SomeView(generic.CreateView):

    #... 

    def get_success_url(self):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`get_success_url` doesn't return an HttpResponseRedirect instead it should return the url you want to redirect to. So you can just return `reverse('index')`:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('index')
```

Answer (score 0):

A shortcut for HttpResponseRedirect is redirect("View_name")
it returns an HttpResponse (HTML)

Reverse returns a url